# Display all product in magento homepage

Tags: magento-1.8

I have the category structure like this..

```
-Default Category (0)
     --Ravi varma (2)
       ---Nature (2)
       ---Religious (0)
     --Da Vinci (2)
     --Michelangelo (1)
     --Picasso(1)
```

`Default category` is the `root category` and all others are subcategory. Subcategory Ravi varma have again two subcategories. Now  I want to display all the product in home page. For this I use the short code:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

But in home page nothing is displayed except the given message.

**There are no products matching the selection.**

For testing I add a product to the `default category`, then that product only displayed in home page. From this I realize that the products belonging to root category only display on home page using this short code. But I can't set all the category as root. So I want to display all the product from all category in home page. How can I do this??

I am using `Magento ver. 1.8.1.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Add all product to the Default category.
```

Since all category are under the Default category all products should belongs to the Default category.

Then your category structure is like:

```
-Default Category (8)
     --Ravi varma (2)
       ---Nature (2)
       ---Religious (0)
     --Da Vinci (2)
     --Michelangelo (1)
     --Picasso(1)
```